# XPath lookup based on sibling value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have been looking for information to do a look up to find the sibling item but cannot find what I need/understand.

**XML**

```
<country>
    <code>GB</code>
    <name>United Kingdom</name>
    <currencysymbol>£</currencysymbol>
</country>
```

**Question**

Is it possible to find the value of currencysymbol node by using the xpath following-sibling when the only value I have to play with is `GB`? I.e. I need to get following-sibling currencysymbol where code=GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath for this, see:

```
/country[code='GB']/currencysymbol
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//code[. = 'GB']/following-sibling::currencysymbol
```